# Does UniqueResult() method return a new object in hibernate criteria query?

Tags: java, hibernate

I need to know if `uniqueResult()` returns a new object, in other words, internally makes a `malloc()`? 
Because my test fails when I compare the memory addresses of the objects.

```
sameObjectButRetrievedByHibernate = sess.createCriteria(Object.class)
                 .add(Restrictions.idEq(someId)).uniqueResult();
...
assertTrue(objetcCreatedByNewAndPersisted == sameObjectButRetrievedByHibernate);
```

Hibernate will always return a copy regardless of whether the object is loaded into memory?

Answer (score 3):

Objects in Java are not created by `malloc` internally, they are stored on heap memory which is already preallocated.

Regarding your question, if an entity instance is already in the persistent context (Hibernate session), then it will be used, otherwise a new one will be created.

So, you are either reading the entity instance in a new session, or you cleared the current session after you persisted the instance.

Comment: Could you explain to me a little more of persisten context (Hibernate session). I understand it is from that I open a session with org.hibernate.SessionFactory.openSession () until I close with org.hibernate.Session.close ()

Comment: Yes, more or less that's the concept.